# Hacer un filtrado de busqueda por fechas con laravel

Tags: php, laravel

soy nuevo en Laravel y no conozco bien sus funciones, mi problema es que tengo que hacer un filtrado de datos para que solo me aparezcan los datos por mes del año ya tengo creado el guaradado con el tipo de dato date para las fechas, lo que quiero saber es como obtener solamente el mes de ese dato guardado y crear un filtro para que solo me aparezcan los datos por un mes especifico

> No se como explicarlo bien porque apenas conozco lo basico de Laravel, pero en esencia lo que quiero es que los datos que estoy enviando desde este controlador se filtren por la fecha en que fueron creados al mostrarse en la vista

```
    public function index()
    {
        // VARIABLES DE TIPO DE CASO
        $sistemas=Sistema::where('tipo', 'Salud');
        $sistemas2=Sistema::where('tipo', 'Denuncia');
        $sistemas3=Sistema::where('tipo', 'Orientacion');
        $sistemas4=Sistema::where('tipo', 'Vivienda');
        $sistemas5=Sistema::where('tipo', 'Pension');
        // VARIABLES CANTIDAD DE PERSONAS
        $cantidad=Sistema::where('cantidad', 'Individual');
        $cantidad1=Sistema::where('cantidad', 'Grupo');
        $cantidad2=Sistema::where('cantidad', 'Consejo Comunal/Comunidad Organizada');
        $cantidad3=Sistema::where('cantidad', 'Trabajador');
        // VARIABLES VIA DE ATENCION
        $via=Sistema::where('via_atencion','Telefonica');
        $via1=Sistema::where('via_atencion','Personalizada');
        $via2=Sistema::where('via_atencion','Correspondencia');
        $via3=Sistema::where('via_atencion','Correo');
        $via4=Sistema::where('via_atencion','Twitter');
        // VARIABLES AYUDA REQUERIDA
        $ayuda=Sistema::where('ayudat','Medicamento');
        $ayuda1=Sistema::where('ayudat','Examen Medico');
        $ayuda2=Sistema::where('ayudat','Articulacion Hosp');
        $ayuda3=Sistema::where('ayudat','Ayuda Tecnica');
        $ayuda4=Sistema::where('ayudat','Lentes');
        $ayuda5=Sistema::where('ayudat','Escaneo CP');
        $ayuda6=Sistema::where('ayudat','Insulina');
        $ayuda7=Sistema::where('ayudat','Quejas Y Reclamos');
        // ESTATUS DEL CASO
        $estatus=Sistema::where('estatus','Seguimiento');
        $estatus1=Sistema::where('estatus','Cerrado');
        return view('Sistema.count',compact('sistemas','sistemas2','sistemas3','sistemas4','sistemas5',
                                            'cantidad','cantidad1','cantidad2','cantidad3',
                                            'via','via1','via2','via3','via4',
                                            'ayuda','ayuda','ayuda1','ayuda2','ayuda3','ayuda4','ayuda5','ayuda6','ayuda7',
                                            'estatus','estatus1'));
    }
```

Comment: Pero los datos se sacan de la BBDD, los tienes a pelo en el código ? Enseña el código ... Imagina que acabas de entrar a este hilo y te encuentras con esas 4 líneas, no te dicen nada....

Comment: los datos los guardo en la base de datos con un formulario que envia lo escrito al controlador y este los guarda en la BD con un CRUD simple

Comment: Para poder proporcionar una respuesta completa y certera necesitamos que aportes mas información como el código que estas utilizando el dato que recives... usa [edit] y modifica la pregunta. Revisa también [ask]. Por otro lado puedes utilizar el método `whereMonth(campo_bd, mes)` revisa la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries

Comment: Xerif tiene razon para poder ayudarte necesitamos al informacion de la migracion de la tabla, el controlador y metodo involucrado para la consulta en el filtro. con este codigo solo nos has enviado el store() el cual no aporta la informacion necesaria para el problema

Comment: Buenas. Vamos progresando. El código que muestras es muy redundante, seguramente haya una forma mucho mejor de hacerlo, hacer 24 consultas seguidas al mismo modelo es síntoma de que algo no estás haciendo bien, ya sea a nivel de base de datos, de la lógica o planteamiento en general. Si sigues adelante sin refactorizar tu proyecto prueba como te indique añadiendo `->whereMonth(campo_bd, mes)` a cada consulta. Por ejemplo para el mes 9: `Sistema::where('tipo', 'Salud')->whereMonth(campo_bd, 9)`

Comment: ya lo hice y si funciono, pero ahora para optimizar debo hacerlo con tablas relacionadas para reducir la redundancia de datos